# Creating simple networkx graph layout for given datapoints

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have datasets of `(50x2)` size. I am able to create `networkx` graph using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
data= DataFrame(50x2)  # this is type and size of data
G= nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='x', target='y', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
pos= nx.spring_layout(G,k=.7)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,5),dpi=300)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=800, with_labels=True, node_color='y')
```

that yields this figure [image: 1]

As you can see the layout of the graph is messy and confusing.

I tried to work with changing `k` values but it does not work. Any idea of how to create such a beautiful layout for my given datasets? thanks in advance

Comment: There are many other built-in layout functions (see here) https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/layout.html. I would suggest the `kamada_kawai_layout` because it uses path lengths as penalties in the layout.

Comment: I tired 'kamada_kawai_layout' but the result is similar to figure 1.